# Will 2 File System Watchers work in different threads concurrently?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, filesystemwatcher

I have a service in vb.net and i am about to set another File system watcher. So i will have 2 in total.
One fswatcher triggers when there is a change in a certain file.txt, and the other one triggers when there is a change in a directory.

Each trigger goes to a different code method. So they do not collide(they dont share the same methods in the app).

So my question is, Is every fswatcher running in a thread? 
So if i get two triggers will the code from fswatcher1 run in another thread than fswatcher2? Or will the one fswatcher wait for the other one to finish 1st?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, though you can set the 'SynchronizingObject' property if you want enable locking mechanism between the two

Comment: Something i forgot to mention, is thats my application its a windows service. Not an actual application(I updated my question now). Am not sure if SynchronizingObject can be applied in service

Comment: SynchronizationObject is simply a locking object, it doesn't matter if you're runnign your FSW as a windows service, windows application or console application. If you want your 2 FSW to work on different threads - forget the SynchronizationObject.

Comment: OK that sums it up.
Thank tou nissim